# Why all changes made during Docker build time are not available during runtime?

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to craft a Docker image that is simply the MongoDB original image plus an admin user account configured on the database. My objective is to simply launch a container with a mongo instance in auth mode and then log into it using `mongo admin -u root -p root`.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log \
    && mongo admin --eval " \
        db.createUser({ user: 'root', pwd: 'root', roles: [ 'root' ]}); \
        db.shutdownServer() \
    "

CMD ["mongod", "--auth"]
```

This is the output of the `docker build --tag lvbarbosa/task-db .` command executed in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM mongo:latest
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
5233d9aed181: Pull complete 
5bbfc055e8fb: Pull complete 
aaf85a329dc4: Pull complete 
1360aef7d266: Pull complete 
9cb9d47c5d80: Pull complete 
80e12bf92c3c: Pull complete 
fd3679b936e6: Pull complete 
5cb080b90ae5: Pull complete 
46cf38664c75: Pull complete 
59693a4ecb90: Pull complete 
dff9fc3b430d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:90b78c44a58d6d927f96baabea3212d8c756017846715b630044aefcabcab2eb
Status: Downloaded newer image for mongo:latest
 ---> 6833171fe0ad
Step 2/3 : RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log     && mongo admin --eval "         db.createUser({ user: 'root', pwd: 'root', roles: [ 'root' ]});         db.shutdownServer()     "
 ---> Running in 6c1a5530b7b6
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 10
child process started successfully, parent exiting
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
Successfully added user: { "user" : "root", "roles" : [ "root" ] }
server should be down...
 ---> 82fa5430003c
Removing intermediate container 6c1a5530b7b6
Step 3/3 : CMD mongod
 ---> Running in 42f240f05661
 ---> 90ec29686438
Removing intermediate container 42f240f05661
Successfully built 90ec29686438
Successfully tagged lvbarbosa/task-db:latest
```

Next, I create a container with that image using `docker run --detach --publish 27017:27017 --name task-db lvbarbosa/task-db`. When I try to connect to the instance using my host's terminal and the command `mongo admin -u root -p root`, logging in fails. I get a `user not found` error message.

It looks like that changes made to the UFS during build time are not persisted. But how come I can download/copy data into the FS during build time and it is available in upper layers and changes to the database files are not? I am confused. This is the complete container log, from start-up time up to the fail logging in attempt.

```
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=86b7b24efed4
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-07-27T13:20:47.687+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-07-27T13:20:47.688+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { security: { authorization: "enabled" } }
2017-07-27T13:20:47.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-27T13:20:47.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-07-27T13:20:47.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-07-27T13:20:47.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3474M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-07-27T13:20:47.719+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-07-27T13:20:47.727+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2017-07-27T13:20:47.727+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2017-07-27T13:20:47.728+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2017-07-27T13:20:47.728+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
2017-07-27T13:20:47.728+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-07-27T13:20:48.963+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 172.17.0.1:45804 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-07-27T13:20:48.963+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.17.0.1:45804 conn1: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.6" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "17.0.0" } }
2017-07-27T13:20:48.970+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on admin from client 172.17.0.1:45804 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user root@admin
2017-07-27T13:20:48.972+0000 I -        [conn1] end connection 172.17.0.1:45804 (1 connection now open)
```

Mongo's original Dockerfile is present in their [github](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/c02ca4cce8c69e5069b75cb574d1b99d7b4edaeb/3.4/Dockerfile).

I have done some research and some people are mentioning an "ephemeral file system" that is used during the DB phase, and that's why changes are not being persisted. Because of that, I should put the user adding functionality on runtime, and not on build time. But there should be a way to configure this during build time, shouldn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the modification are made in `/data/db` or `/data/configdb`. But in the base mongodb image, those folders are [declared as `VOLUME`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/c02ca4cce8c69e5069b75cb574d1b99d7b4edaeb/3.4/Dockerfile#L71), and accordingly to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume):

> **Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile**: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I thought that it was something related to the `Removing intermediate container 6c1a5530b7b6` step. Do you know if there's another way to add the user during build time without creating a completely new `Dockerfile` from a Linux image and downloading/setting up everything before the `VOLUME` declaration?

Comment: I guess you have to do it after starting a container based on the mongodb image: https://docs.docker.com/samples/mongo/#authentication-and-authorization